# What is the best way to notify backend that push notifications have been disabled?

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, notifications, apple-push-notifications

What's the best way to notify a backend that a user has disabled push notifications?

I've been playing around with a few options but I'm not sure which is the best one to proceed with:
**Option 1:**
Check if the user has disabled push notifications in the `applicationDidFinishLaunching` method like this:

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getNotificationSettings { ... }
```

The only pitfall to this is let's say a user disables push notifications, and then never reopens the app. The `applicationDidFinishLaunching` method will never get called and therefore my app will never realize notifications were disabled and won't act appropriately.

**Option 2:** Is there a way backend is able to check if notifications have been disabled?

Comment: If the user *"never reopens the app"* ... how could your app act either appropriately or inappropriately? It's not acting at all.

Comment: @DonMag That's what I mean. It wouldn't be able to act at all and therefore I would never be able to notify backend that the user has disabled notifications.

Comment: APNS Feedback Service? See: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/BinaryProviderAPI.html

Comment: Nope, I think I have actually figured it out. Apple sends a 410 status code if the user has disabled push notifications

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so after looking through the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CommunicatingwithAPNs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH11-SW15) I may have figured it out.

Apple should send a 410 status code if the device token is no longer active which means that the user must have stopped push notifications or deleted the app.